# Does HikariCP execute queries in background?

Tags: hikaricp

I read about [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and there's an information:

One `Statement` Cycle is defined as single `Connection.prepareStatement()`, `Statement.execute()`, `Statement.close()`.

My question is simple:

If I call this on a main thread: HikariData.getConnection().executeStmt(stmt);

will it run on a main thread and will block it (if the query is big) or will run in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run on your current thread.

Comment: how do you know that? :)

Comment: Several reasons: 1) HikariCP os an implementation of JDBC connection pool interface which specifies such behaviour 2) Connection pool is simply storage of open db connections which are reused, thus saving time for opening new connections, not thread pool